# Looking for an appropriate DBMS

Tags: database

I have some applications I want to write that have similar data needs and I'm having trouble figuring out which DBMS would be best. I want something open source, with a reasonable license (not MySQL).

One application is a "family information" application which is a combination contact, family tree, family history, and photo/metadata tracker. The data needs are thus fairly moderate (by modern standards).

Part of the problem is that I'm not entirely sure that what I want to do would be easy, or even possible in an RDBMS, which is pretty much all I'm familiar with. I might even need to use multiple DBMS's for different aspects.

The data I want to store contains three main parts: Parent nodes, data nodes, and properties.

A parent node consists of identifying information, a list of child nodes, and a set of properties.

A data (child) node contains some kind of content, which will either be text or binary data, and a set of properties.

Properties are key/value pairs, where the value is something reasonably simple - a primitive (boolean, byte, int, double, etc), date, enumerated type, or a reasonably short string. The properties are the part of this that I'm having the most trouble with - figuring out how to store properties of different types in a way where they can be transparently accessed despite the different data types.

Please recommend some kind of data storage library that would allow me to implement such a system with a minimum of difficulty in a Java Virtual Machine environment (Java and/or Scala).

Comment: Number of data points? Any speed requirements? OS? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen - how's that? I can edit it some more if there is something in particular I should add.

Answer (score 3):

A free database I've used and liked is [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). It can be used locally or as a small-to-medium multiuser DB, has an *extremely* small footprint, and there are a number of libraries available for it. It is low weight and low maintenance, and conforms to ISO/IEC 9075 *Database Language SQL*.

A minimal install, however, does not have all the functions of a DBMS such as Oracle, but you can choose what libraries (UDF and DLL) to add. See also https://www.ibphoenix.com/ and [IBExpert Personal Edition](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.PersonalEdition), and excellent DB browser and manager.

Comment: Given the OP's requirements, Firebird is indeed good enough for him.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a RDBMS. I recommend Postgres. http://www.postgresql.org/. You can alternatively store the binary data on disk and use the database to store the file name.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I don't know what to say. Postgres is the most popular DB after Oracle and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful, if you would clarify whether parent and child nodes are expected to form a tree-like structure or a network-like structure. Regardless of that, a system that you describe can be built, using pretty much any type of modern database systems or libraries: relational, object-oriented, multi-paradigm, hierarchical, network [those are rare] as well as document-oriented and other [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database systems. It is just a matter of **prioritizing** or **balancing** *requirements*, *features*, *development platform* of choice, etc.

Obviously, if you'd be more specific about your *data model*, answers could be more helpful. For example, if your data model would be *hierarchical*, discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/2872891) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4767944/2872891) would provide more concrete opinions or recommendations. Depending on your system's requirements, you may even do well by using some kind of a simple JSON storage (see NoSQL information via the corresponding link above).

The choice can also be impacted by the system's *intended use* (choice software with the right *license* might be tricky), a *programming language (development platform)* that you plan to use for the system as well as whether the system should support *multiple platforms* and which (both development and target).

Answer (score 2):

## Postgres

Postgres is a good choice as suggested in another answer.

### License

Postgres is truly open-source and free-of-cost, with its own utterly simple ["do anything but sue us" license](http://opensource.org/licenses/postgresql).

### Key-Value Store

Postgres has had a key-value store feature called [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) long before "no-SQL" became a buzzword.

And now Postgres has amazing new support for [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data including indexing of nested elements, which you could treat as a whole new key-value store feature. For this use the [newer `JSONB` data](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) type rather than original `JSON` type. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql) for discussion.

### Quality

Postgres is known for its enterprise-quality, rock-solid stability, regular development cadence, security mindedness, and safe and sane engineering approach.

### Nodes

I don't know what you mean by parent child nodes. Perhaps you just mean two tables in a one-to-many relationship. That is what relational databases are built for. Like invoice and invoice lines, or patient and doctor visits.

### Java

Postgres is native code, written in C. So it is not Java and does not run in the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

You use either of the two open-source [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) drivers to connect your Java app. Choose either the [classic driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) or the ["next-generation" driver](https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) rewritten from scratch to drop support for legacy versions of Java, JDBC, and Postgres.

### Install

Postgres is a heavy install, creating a new OS-level user account "postgres" and creating folder hierarchy owned by that user. This is all for security. Uninstalling is possible but a bit of a chore. I suggest experimenting with Postgres inside a virtualizer such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), or VMware Fusion so you can simply trash the VM file rather than uninstall.